# Can I make changes to a svelte store inside its own subscribe() function?

Tags: svelte

Suppose I have a writable store:

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const robot = writable({
  weight: 10, // will bind to a slider
  allowJump: true, // will bind to a toggle
});
```

I want to auto toggle off `allowJump` when robot is too heavy, am I allowed to do something like this?:

```js
robot.subscribe((value) => {
  if (value.weight > 100) value.allowJump = false;
});
```

If not, maybe something like this?:

```js
robot.subscribe((value) => {
  if (value.weight > 100) $robot.allowJump = false;
});
```

Or this?:

```js
robot.subscribe((value) => {
  if (value.weight > 100) robot.update((prev) => (prev.allowJump = false));
});
```

Comment: It will loop if weight > 100, because the update triggers the store, which will trigger the update et cetera;

Comment: @voscausa there's only one update so it won't loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're doing it in the same file where you create the store, The 1st way in your code is the right way. It'll work, and you don't need to think about unsubscribe. Just be sure not to create infinite loops.

The 2nd way in your code won't work, because `$store` doesn't work outside of components.

The 3rd way will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to create  `robotCanJump` store derived from `robot` store.

```js
import { derived, writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const robot = writable({
    weight: 10,
    allowJump: true,
})

export const robotCanJump = derived(
    robot,
    $robot => $robot.weight < 100 && $robot.allowJump
);
```

Then you can use it in your Svelte component like this:

```
<script>
    import { robot, robotCanJump } from './stores.js';
</script>

Weight:
<input type="number" bind:value={$robot.weight} />
<br />
AllowJump:
<input type="checkbox" bind:checked={$robot.allowJump} />

<p>
    {#if $robotCanJump}
    Can jump!
    {:else}
    Cannot jump
    {/if}
</p>
```

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/aac1960c1c5344348741979591dd4975?version=3.58.0

Comment: Thanks. I picked the other answer because in your example, the checkbox will not auto toggle off when the user is interacting with the number.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to use `subscribe` in a component and if you use it you should make sure to unsubscribe.

In a component you can just use a reactive statement:

```js
$: if ($robot.weight > 100)
    $robot.allowJump = false;
```

If the change is done in `subscribe` like the following:

```js
const unsubscribe = robot.subscribe($robot => {
    if ($robot.weight > 100)
        $robot.allowJump = false;
});
```

This may already work as well because component updates are deferred to the end of a frame so components should only see the updated value.

Comment: That is only valid if the lifetime of the store is also infinite; as soon as you e.g. have multiple robot instances with limited lifetime, you may want to clean up accordingly. Though in this case, leaving the subscription alone would not be an issue as its code does not reference anything else, so it should not cause any leaks or other problems.